# How to draw a 2D chart with categorical variables (plus marginals)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am attempting to draw a `jointplot` style chart using two **categorical** variables, e.g. from the [Adult data-set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult).

I am using a `heatmap` instead of `hexbin` because the later doesn't allow x-axis to be categorical.

Two problems occur ... the axes look misaligned although the joint by itself and the marginals by themselves look fine. The second (and probably related) is that the x-axis of the joint part disappears.

Here is (part) of my code.

```
# 1 - lets choose two categorical (string) columns
features = [ 'education', 'workclass' ]
# 2 - calculate the 2D/joint histogram 
xhmap = df[features].groupby(features).size().to_frame('BIN_COUNT').reset_index()
# 3 - needed by heatmap
pxhmap = xhmap.pivot_table(values='BIN_COUNT',index=features[0], columns=features[1])

# 4 - create a joint grid
g = sns.JointGrid(x=features[0], y=features[1], data=xhmap)
# 5 - draw stacked bar charts on the marginals
_draw_categorical(g.ax_marg_x, features[1], inner=True)
_draw_categorical(g.ax_marg_y, features[0], inner=True, bar_type='barh')
# 6 - draw a heat map (couldn't find a way to draw a hexbin here)
chart = sns.heatmap(data=pxhmap, cmap='Blues', cbar=False, ax=g.ax_joint)

# 7 - Would like to highlight a subset of the heatmap ...
shmap = df_sub[features].groupby(features).size().to_frame('BIN_COUNT').reset_index()
pshmap = shmap.pivot_table(values='BIN_COUNT',index=features[0], columns=features[1])
chart = sns.heatmap(data=pshmap, cmap='Reds', alpha=0.5, cbar=False, ax=g.ax_joint)


def _draw_categorical(self, ax1, feat, bar_type='bar', inner=False):
    h = [ d.value_counts() for d in self._get_data(feat) ]
    df = pd.concat(h, axis=1, keys=self.labels, sort=True)
    need_log = self._is_log_axis_needed(df.sum(axis=1).values)
    chart = df.plot(kind=bar_type, stacked=True, color=self.colors, log=need_log, alpha=0.65, ax=ax1)
    if inner:
        chart.get_legend().remove()
    else:           
        chart.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size': 10})
        chart.set_xticklabels(chart.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8, rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
        chart.set_xlabel(feat)
        chart.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
```

This *almost* creates what I want.
After (4) I get an empty chart; (5) draws the marginals properly, but then when drawing (6) the axes get misaligned (or similar). See screen-shots below.

After step (4)
[image: after step 4]

After first part of step (5) ... already a problem as x-axis disappears!
[image]

After step (5).

[image]

After step (6). Note the misalignment.

[image]

Running step (6) before (5) creates this

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is `_draw_categorical()` ?

Comment: Could you make sure you have the latest versions of matplotlib and seaborn installed? (Some time ago there was a problem with seaborn's heatmaps being cut off half a cell near the top and the bottom.)

Comment: @DizietAsahi `_draw_categorical()` is the method that draws stacked bar charts (instead of a simple histogram) on the marginals. I don't think it is relevant as drawing it looks properly aligned.

Comment: @mibm Anything that stops your example code from being reproducible, is very relevant.

Comment: @JohanC my `seaborn` is practically the latest `0.10.0` and `matplotlib` quite recent `3.1.3` while latest is `3.3.1`. Do you know when that problem was fixed?

Comment: Found that seaborn bug ... a year ago https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773. My version is newer. Also I don't see that problem before drawing the marginals (would be visible in the screen shots above).

Comment: the issue with heatmaps was resolved in `3.1.2`.

Comment: the heatmap works fine one its own according to your screenshot, so it is drawing the marginals that causes problem, which is why I was asking for the code for that `_draw_caterogrical()` function

Comment: @DizietAsahi drawing the marginals first also looks fine (see screen shot). I am adding that method anyway to the question.

Comment: @DizietAsahi @JohanC I found out that the limits are `0~9` when either join of marginal are draw then become `-0.5~8.5` after the other is draw. Looks like there is some link between the joint x/y-axis and the one in the marginal. Hiding the x/y-axis of marginal also hides the one in the joint ... maybe they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, the problem is that you are mixing up seaborn's plotting with pandas' plotting, which do not use the same coordinate system when dealing with categorical data.

Since you are calculating the pivot table by hand anyway, I would recommend you get rid of `sns.heatmap` alltogether and plot the heatmap directly using `imshow`

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x=features[0], y=features[1], data=xhmap)

# draw heatmap
g.ax_joint.imshow(pxhmap, aspect='auto', cmap='Reds')
g.ax_joint.set_xticks(range(pxhmap.columns.size))
g.ax_joint.set_xticklabels(pxhmap.columns, rotation=90, ha='center')
g.ax_joint.set_yticks(range(pxhmap.index.size))
g.ax_joint.set_yticklabels(pxhmap.index)

# draw marginals
_draw_categorical(...)
_draw_categorical(...)
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! Would it be possible to draw a second heatmap with a subset of the x and y categories on top? (without filling the missing values with NaN explicitly)

Comment: probably, but if you want things to align correctly, I would advise you generate a dataframe that is the same shape / same index / same columns as `pxhmap`. You may want to ask a new question with a MVCE if you need help

Comment: I generated a dataframe for the subset using `pd.DataFrame(columns=whole_data.columns, index=whole_data.index, data=subset_data` as suggested. This basically creates an empty data frame of the same shape and copies the subset into it based on index.